# Right place to add "Staging preview" to Workflow in Experience Manager?

Tags: cme, experience-manager, workflow

**Is the user info bar notifications for workflow the same between Experience Manager and the Content Manager Explorer?** I'm looking for good places to extend the multi-item workflow preview.

[image: Workflow Pop-up]

Ideally the *open* shortcut would go to the staging url of an item or offer the choice to open the item in the CME or view on staging. **Would "Related Items" be a good (extendable) place to consider for this?**

The other options I'm thinking would be to make sure CME preview looked like Staging, create emails similar to [YAWF](http://www.julianwraith.com/sdl-tridion-community-webinars/community-webinar-9th-november-2011/), or somehow change the [Outlook Connector](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/ConnectorForOutlook.aspx) email screens (is that possible?).

Comment: Congratulations on 1000 question :)

Comment: Just a note, remember that "view in staging" is not something generic, every implementation can have a different publishing model. Just to give you an example, imagine your customer is using CWA... how would you make the preview (in the CME) look like Staging? That would be a lot of effort. I like better to use a link that opens a page in Staging, since that's the real deal. In that case you need to consider what are you gonna do when selecting a component to "view in staging", Ideally you want to present the user a list of pages where the component is used, and then, provide with the page url

Comment: Yep, that's the thinking. A link or setting up the preview template to post "serialized content" to the site as needed would be specific to the setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are the same .Net user control. It is called UserInfo and it is called like this in pages.

```
<ui:UserInfoBar id="UserNotification" runat="server" />
```

or if called from a different editor than CME

```
<ui:UserInfoBar id="UserNotification" runat="server" SourceEditor="CME" />
```

The related items area is not extendable out of the box, but if you do some hack and add an extendable area then you can extend things there. For instance this is the markup by default.

```
<div id="ActivityRelatedListButtonWrapper">
    <c:Button id="BtnPreview" disabled="disabled" runat="server" Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Preview %>" Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Preview %>" />
    <c:Button id="BtnCompare" disabled="disabled" runat="server" Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Compare %>" Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Compare %>" />
    <c:Button id="OpenActivityRelatedItem" disabled="disabled" runat="server" Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Open %>" />
</div>
```

You can add an extendable area like this.

```
<div id="ActivityRelatedListButtonWrapper">
<c:ExtendableArea id="Pre_ExtendableArea" runat="server" />
    <c:Button id="BtnPreview" disabled="disabled" runat="server" Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Preview %>" Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Preview %>" />
    <c:Button id="BtnCompare" disabled="disabled" runat="server" Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Compare %>" Title="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Compare %>" />
    <c:Button id="OpenActivityRelatedItem" disabled="disabled" runat="server" Label="<%$ Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Open %>" />
<c:ExtendableArea id="Post_ExtendableArea" runat="server" />
</div>
```

These extendable areas can be used to inject a .Net User Control.

Tridion 2013 Workflow gives you a `Object Oriented` capabilities that can be used to define external activities specialized on `Email Dispatching` similar of what you have with YAWF. However if you really need a `Handlers` behavior like YAWF you can do it by extending the Script Executor as I describe in this post [Extending Workflow Scripts](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/04/extending-tridion-2013-workflow-scripts.html)

Comment: Thanks for the options and examples from your post. In this use case, several reviewers would be outside the CMS, so we might want to look into the email approach.